# inno setup crashed when trying to close applications

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

I have a problem. My inno script contains `CloseAppliactions` set to `yes`. When the installer goes to the specified step and tries to perform it, my app crashes. What't wrong?

Comment: Does your application crash (as per text: *"my app crashes"*) or the installer (as per title: *"inno setup crashed"*)?

Comment: First my app crashed, and then inno setup as well.

Comment: What does it look like when the installer crashes?

Comment: Actually, it crashed because of some kernel dll's. It looks like restart manager closes my app via TerminateProcess, but not WM_CLOSE

Comment: Possibly because the application does not respond to `WM_CLOSE`?

Comment: WM_CLOSE is handled pretty well. It is a big app. There're a lot of threads doing a lot of stuff. May be, some default system timeout is not enough to allow my app finished correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug your application to see why it crashes when it is shut down unexpectedly by another process.

The Inno Setup calls [`RmShutdown` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/nf-restartmanager-rmshutdown) to shut down the applications that have the files needing an update locked.

The function sends some message to the applications to shut them down. Probably `WM_QUIT`, but possibly others. Your application handles this (other another) message wrongly.